# Getters for FXML controllers in the controller class instead of lookup?

Tags: java, javafx, java-8, javafx-8

I'm loading fxmls in `start()` and I want to place them in the main window which has say a borderPane.

```
        FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader();
        loader.setLocation(Main.class.getResource("Resources/Game.fxml"));
        Parent root = loader.load();
        GameController gameManagerController = loader.getController();

        loader = new FXMLLoader();
        loader.setLocation(getClass().getResource("Resources/TopMenuBar.fxml"));
        Parent topMenuBar = loader.load();
        TopMenuBarController topMenuBarController = loader.getController();
```

Now lookup for the borderPane in the `root` is returning null, even though I did give it an id (not fx:id). So my question is, is acceptable to instead write a getter for the borderPane in the `gameManagerController` and do something like this instead?

```
gameManagerController.getBorderPane().setTop(topMenuBar);
```

Comment: It's not usually a good idea to expose UI elements from your controller (though it's probably better than using lookups, which are very fragile). At a minimum, define a method in `GameController` to display the menu, so you can call `gameManagerController.showMenu(topMenuBar)` (name the method whatever is appropriate). You could also consider using a "view model", but it is probably overkill in this situation.

Comment: What will `showMenu()` do? Will it do this: `BorderPane.setTop(topMenuBar);`? @James_D

Comment: I would replace `BorderPane` with a more appropriate field name in the controller, but yes, that is the idea. The point is that if you decide to change how the layout is managed, all the changes are restricted to the controller and FXML, you wouldn't need to change code outside of that. Using your suggested solution, it becomes much harder to maintain or change your UI if you need to later.

Comment: Of course I use meaningful names for everything. I see now, thanks again. @James_D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not usually a good idea to expose UI elements outside of the controller. Doing so makes it much harder to change how you organize the UI later, as you may have code outside the controller-FXML pair that depends on a specific layout or on specific UI element classes being present.

A simple, but more robust solution, is just to define a method for the purpose of displaying a menu in `GameController`:

```
public class GameController {

    @FXML
    private BorderPane rootPane ;

    // ...

    public void showMenu(Node menu) {
        rootPane.setTop(menu);
    }

    // ...
}
```

and now you can do

```
gameManagerController.showMenu(topMenuBar);
```

---

A more complex approach, which might be overkill for this situation but is nevertheless worth seeing, is to use a "view model" to represent the view state of the application.

```
public class ApplicationViewState {

    private final ObjectProperty<Node> menu = new SimpleObjectProperty<>();
    private final ObjectProperty<Node> content = new SimpleObjectProperty<>();

    public ObjectProperty<Node> menuProperty() {
        return menu ;
    }

    public final Node getMenu() {
        return menuProperty().get();
    }

    public final void setMenu(Node menu) {
        menuProperty().set(menu);
    }


    public ObjectProperty<Node> contentProperty() {
        return content ;
    }

    public final Node getContent() {
        return contentProperty().get();
    }

    public final void setContent(Node content) {
        contentProperty().set(content);
    }

    // ...
}
```

Now you can share a single instance of the view model among the controllers, which can observe and update the state as they need:

```
public class GameController {

    @FXML
    private BorderPane rootPane ;

    private ApplicationViewState viewState ;

    public void setViewState(ApplicationViewState viewState) {
        this.viewState = viewState ;
        rootPane.topProperty().bind(viewState.menuProperty());
    }

    // ...
}
```

and then

```
FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader();
loader.setLocation(Main.class.getResource("Resources/Game.fxml"));
Parent root = loader.load();
GameController gameManagerController = loader.getController();

loader = new FXMLLoader();
loader.setLocation(getClass().getResource("Resources/TopMenuBar.fxml"));
Parent topMenuBar = loader.load();
TopMenuBarController topMenuBarController = loader.getController();


ApplicationViewState viewState = new ApplicationViewState();
gameManagerController.setViewState(viewState);
viewState.setMenu(topMenuBar);
```

The advantage of this approach is that it provides a mechanism for any controller to update the UI in other parts of the application, without having to "know about" other controllers. This aids in decoupling the various parts of your UI. The disadvantage is increased complexity of the application - it can be hard to debug because it's less clear how different things are happening in the UI.

Comment: Is 'ApplicationViewState' a facade pattern?

Comment: No; not really. It's really just a model in MVC.